# Reading a file containing two arrays whose elements appear in consecutive lines

Tags: python, pandas

So, folks, I tried to browse a solution to the following problem but without success. I have basic knowledge of python, and in this case, I have no idea where to start.

I have a data file with the following structure:

```
A  B
1  10
1  17
1  21
1  22
2  30
2  150
2  33
2  155
2  35
2  170
2  40
2  172
1  100
1  90
etc
```

When A = 1 it means that the value of B is unique and belongs to a given array b1. But when A = 2, I have to consider two consecutive lines, such that the value in the first line belongs to array b1 and the value in the second line belongs to array b2.

In the example above, I wish to extract from the file the following arrays:

```
b1 = [10,17,21,22,30,33,35,40,100,90,...]
b2 = [150,155,170,172,...]
```

Ok, you may think that since the values of b2 are all larger than 100, I could use that property to separate them, but that is not the issue. The example above is a very simplified version of the actual file, and what I need is that each time I read a 2 in A, I have to consider that line and the following line and load the consecutive values of B into different arrays.

By the way, the actual problem could be even more complex, since I may have A=3, which means that I have to considere three consecutive lines and load them into three different arrays.

Any reasonable solution? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is an example of the actual file

```
    k2   k1     ecc            a1_in          a1_out         a2_in          a2_out          T_max      Neq     sigma          period
    2    1    0.00000E+00    2.71687E+00    2.72413E+00    4.23040E+00    4.40685E+00    6.06516E+00    1    0.00000E+00    2.90421E+02
    2    1    1.21212E-02    2.71673E+00    2.72427E+00    4.22704E+00    4.41021E+00    6.06516E+00    1    1.00000E+00    3.05916E+02
    2    1    2.12121E-02    2.71662E+00    2.72438E+00    4.22438E+00    4.41286E+00    6.06516E+00    1    2.00000E+00    3.21540E+02
    2    1    2.42424E-02    2.71659E+00    2.72441E+00    4.22346E+00    4.41378E+00    6.06516E+00    1    3.00000E+00    3.26975E+02
    2    1    2.72727E-02    2.71655E+00    2.72445E+00    4.22253E+00    4.41472E+00    6.06516E+00    1    4.00000E+00    3.32587E+02
    2    1    3.03030E-02    2.71651E+00    2.72449E+00    4.22157E+00    4.41568E+00    6.06516E+00    1    5.00000E+00    3.38341E+02
    2    1    3.33333E-02    2.71647E+00    2.72453E+00    4.22059E+00    4.41666E+00    6.06516E+00    1    6.00000E+00    3.44197E+02
    2    1    3.63636E-02    2.71643E+00    2.72457E+00    4.21958E+00    4.41767E+00    6.06516E+00    1    7.00000E+00    3.50106E+02
    2    1    1.00000E-01    2.71521E+00    2.72579E+00    4.18991E+00    4.44734E+00    6.06516E+00    2    4.90000E+01    2.10904E+02
    2    1    1.00000E-01    2.71521E+00    2.72579E+00    4.18991E+00    4.44734E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.91000E+02    4.36205E+02
    2    1    1.03030E-01    2.71513E+00    2.72587E+00    4.18805E+00    4.44920E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.00000E+01    2.06022E+02
    2    1    1.03030E-01    2.71513E+00    2.72587E+00    4.18805E+00    4.44920E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.86000E+02    3.54965E+02
    2    1    1.06061E-01    2.71505E+00    2.72595E+00    4.18615E+00    4.45110E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.10000E+01    2.01226E+02
    2    1    1.06061E-01    2.71505E+00    2.72595E+00    4.18615E+00    4.45110E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.82000E+02    3.10402E+02
    2    1    1.09091E-01    2.71497E+00    2.72603E+00    4.18420E+00    4.45305E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.20000E+01    1.96524E+02
    2    1    1.09091E-01    2.71497E+00    2.72603E+00    4.18420E+00    4.45305E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.79000E+02    2.84028E+02
    2    1    1.12121E-01    2.71489E+00    2.72611E+00    4.18222E+00    4.45503E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.30000E+01    1.91922E+02
    2    1    1.12121E-01    2.71489E+00    2.72611E+00    4.18222E+00    4.45503E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.76000E+02    2.61260E+02
    2    1    1.15152E-01    2.71481E+00    2.72619E+00    4.18020E+00    4.45705E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.50000E+01    1.84228E+02
    2    1    1.15152E-01    2.71481E+00    2.72619E+00    4.18020E+00    4.45705E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.74000E+02    2.47983E+02
    2    1    1.18182E-01    2.71472E+00    2.72628E+00    4.17814E+00    4.45911E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.60000E+01    1.79925E+02
    2    1    1.18182E-01    2.71472E+00    2.72628E+00    4.17814E+00    4.45911E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.72000E+02    2.35614E+02
```

The columns I am interested in are Neq and sigma

Comment: what format is the input data in? Would you be able to provide the A  B
1  10
1  17
1  21
1  22 etc. data?

Comment: @MarkHill I will add an example of the exact file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 2 (or more) separate lists, it might be possible to use a dictionary with a key of 1, 2, etc. This would allow for 3 for example.

```
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

data = """\
    k2   k1     ecc            a1_in          a1_out         a2_in          a2_out          T_max      Neq     sigma          period
    2    1    0.00000E+00    2.71687E+00    2.72413E+00    4.23040E+00    4.40685E+00    6.06516E+00    1    0.00000E+00    2.90421E+02
    2    1    1.21212E-02    2.71673E+00    2.72427E+00    4.22704E+00    4.41021E+00    6.06516E+00    1    1.00000E+00    3.05916E+02
    2    1    2.12121E-02    2.71662E+00    2.72438E+00    4.22438E+00    4.41286E+00    6.06516E+00    1    2.00000E+00    3.21540E+02
    2    1    2.42424E-02    2.71659E+00    2.72441E+00    4.22346E+00    4.41378E+00    6.06516E+00    1    3.00000E+00    3.26975E+02
    2    1    2.72727E-02    2.71655E+00    2.72445E+00    4.22253E+00    4.41472E+00    6.06516E+00    1    4.00000E+00    3.32587E+02
    2    1    3.03030E-02    2.71651E+00    2.72449E+00    4.22157E+00    4.41568E+00    6.06516E+00    1    5.00000E+00    3.38341E+02
    2    1    3.33333E-02    2.71647E+00    2.72453E+00    4.22059E+00    4.41666E+00    6.06516E+00    1    6.00000E+00    3.44197E+02
    2    1    3.63636E-02    2.71643E+00    2.72457E+00    4.21958E+00    4.41767E+00    6.06516E+00    1    7.00000E+00    3.50106E+02
    2    1    1.00000E-01    2.71521E+00    2.72579E+00    4.18991E+00    4.44734E+00    6.06516E+00    2    4.90000E+01    2.10904E+02
    2    1    1.00000E-01    2.71521E+00    2.72579E+00    4.18991E+00    4.44734E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.91000E+02    4.36205E+02
    2    1    1.03030E-01    2.71513E+00    2.72587E+00    4.18805E+00    4.44920E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.00000E+01    2.06022E+02
    2    1    1.03030E-01    2.71513E+00    2.72587E+00    4.18805E+00    4.44920E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.86000E+02    3.54965E+02
    2    1    1.06061E-01    2.71505E+00    2.72595E+00    4.18615E+00    4.45110E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.10000E+01    2.01226E+02
    2    1    1.06061E-01    2.71505E+00    2.72595E+00    4.18615E+00    4.45110E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.82000E+02    3.10402E+02
    2    1    1.09091E-01    2.71497E+00    2.72603E+00    4.18420E+00    4.45305E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.20000E+01    1.96524E+02
    2    1    1.09091E-01    2.71497E+00    2.72603E+00    4.18420E+00    4.45305E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.79000E+02    2.84028E+02
    2    1    1.12121E-01    2.71489E+00    2.72611E+00    4.18222E+00    4.45503E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.30000E+01    1.91922E+02
    2    1    1.12121E-01    2.71489E+00    2.72611E+00    4.18222E+00    4.45503E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.76000E+02    2.61260E+02
    2    1    1.15152E-01    2.71481E+00    2.72619E+00    4.18020E+00    4.45705E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.50000E+01    1.84228E+02
    2    1    1.15152E-01    2.71481E+00    2.72619E+00    4.18020E+00    4.45705E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.74000E+02    2.47983E+02
    2    1    1.18182E-01    2.71472E+00    2.72628E+00    4.17814E+00    4.45911E+00    6.06516E+00    2    5.60000E+01    1.79925E+02
    2    1    1.18182E-01    2.71472E+00    2.72628E+00    4.17814E+00    4.45911E+00    6.06516E+00    2    2.72000E+02    2.35614E+02"""

with StringIO(data) as f:
    d = dict()
    next(f)  # throw away header
    for line in f:
        Neq, sigma = line.split()[-3:-1]
        d.setdefault('1', []).append(sigma)
        
        for i in range(2, int(Neq)+1):
            line = next(f)
            sigma = line.split()[-2]
            d.setdefault(str(i), []).append(sigma)
        
pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'1': ['0.00000E+00',
       '1.00000E+00',
       '2.00000E+00',
       '3.00000E+00',
       '4.00000E+00',
       '5.00000E+00',
       '6.00000E+00',
       '7.00000E+00',
       '4.90000E+01',
       '5.00000E+01',
       '5.10000E+01',
       '5.20000E+01',
       '5.30000E+01',
       '5.50000E+01',
       '5.60000E+01'],
 '2': ['2.91000E+02',
       '2.86000E+02',
       '2.82000E+02',
       '2.79000E+02',
       '2.76000E+02',
       '2.74000E+02',
       '2.72000E+02']}
```

Comment: I like very much this solution. I didn't work with dictionaries before, it seems very powerful. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCharley, your script is quite clear. I only made a few adaptations, because I need to read also some other columns in the file (so, I created the corresponding dictionaries) and then transform the dictionaries into numpy arrays. But is working awesome.

Answer (score 2):

use a counter that resets every time A is one, then increment and test for odd or even when A is two.

```
data = '''A  B
          1  10
          1  17
          1  21
          1  22
          2  30
          2  150
          2  33
          2  155
          2  35
          2  170
          2  40
          2  172
          1  100
          1  90'''

count, b1, b2 = 0, [], []
for row in data.splitlines()[1:]:
    a, b = list(map(int, row.split()))
    if a == 1:
        count = 0
        b1.append(b)
    elif a == 2:
        count += 1
        if not count % 2:
            b2.append(b)
        else:
            b1.append(b)

print(f'{b1= }')
print(f'{b2= }')
```

output:

```
b1= [10, 17, 21, 22, 30, 33, 35, 40, 100, 90]
b2= [150, 155, 170, 172]
```

Comment: Thank you @richard. So,your idea is more or less what I would have done in C. It works great and I will use it. Bur I am pretty sure that there would be another way to do it using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    'B': [10, 17, 21, 22, 30, 150, 33, 155, 35, 170, 40, 172, 100, 90],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

condition = df['A'].eq(2)
cumulative_sum = condition.cumsum().where(condition).combine_first(df['A']) % 2
mask_odd = cumulative_sum.eq(1)
mask_even = cumulative_sum.eq(0)
b1 = df['B'][mask_odd]
b2 = df['B'][mask_even]
display(b1, b2)
>>>
[10, 17, 21, 22, 30, 33, 35, 40, 100, 90]

[150, 155, 170, 172]
```

Comment: Thanks @ziyng35. This is a quite elegant solution, but it will work ok only with 1s and 2s in A. It will not work if I have 3s in A, for example, 'A':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]